# Jasper Reports Save PDF to disk

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, jasper-reports

I'm using Jasper Reports within Spring. Is it possible to let Jasper generate the PDF of the report and save it to the file system?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Of course. In fact, JasperReports includes [an export parameter](http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/api/net/sf/jasperreports/engine/JRExporterParameter.html#OUTPUT_FILE_NAME) for doing just that. Basically, you setup your exporter however you are doing so now and set the `JRExportParameter.OUTPUT_FILE_NAME` parameter to the name of the file you want to save the report as, and then export the report as per normal.

Comment: Thanks, I guess this will work, as Spring provides a way to set these Export-parameters: http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/reference/view.html (Section 16.7.5)! I really appreciate your help :)

Comment: How to make exported pdf report to be downloadable to user by displaying the pop u window

Answer (score 0):

You can write the bytes received from JRPdfExporter to a local file instead of the response stream. The exact solution will depend on how you are using Jasper in your application.